# How to control (i.e. abort) the current evaluation of a QScriptEngine

Tags: c++, qt, asynchronous, future, qtconcurrent

I evaluate JavaScript in my Qt application using [`QScriptEngine::evaluate(QString code)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qscriptengine.html#evaluate). Let's say I evaluate a buggy piece of JavaScript which loops forever (or takes too long to wait for the result). How can I *abort* such an execution?

I want to control an evaluation via two buttons `Run` and `Abort` in a GUI. (But only one execution is allowed at a time.)

I thought of running the script via [`QtConcurrent::run`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtconcurrentrun.html), keeping the [`QFuture`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfuture.html) and calling [`cancel()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfuture.html#cancel) when the `Abort` is was pressed. But the documentation says that I can't abort such executions. It seems like `QFuture` only cancels after the current item in the job has been processed, i.e. when reducing or filtering a collection. But for `QtConcurrent::run` this means that I can't use the future to abort its execution.

The other possibility I came up with was using a [`QThread`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html) and calling [`quit()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html#quit), but there I have a similar problems: It only cancels the thread if / as soon as it is waiting in an event loop. But since my execution is a single function call, this is no option either.

`QThread` also has [`terminate()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html#terminate), but the documentation makes me worry a bit. Although my code itself doesn't involve mutexes, maybe `QScriptEngine::evaluate` does behind the scenes?

> **Warning:** This function is dangerous and its use is discouraged. The thread can be terminated at any point in its code path. Threads can be terminated while modifying data. There is no chance for the thread to clean up after itself, unlock any held mutexes, etc. In short, use this function only if absolutely necessary.

Is there another option I am missing, maybe some asynchronous evaluation feature?

Answer (score 1):

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qscriptengine.html#details

It has a few sections that address your concerns:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qscriptengine.html#long-running-scripts

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qscriptengine.html#script-exceptions

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qscriptengine.html#abortEvaluation

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qscriptengine.html#setProcessEventsInterval

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. I figured out and posted the solution by myself. Should have read the doc more. ;) Thank you anyway for the links.

Answer (score 0):

While the concurrent task itself can't be aborted "from outside", the `QScriptEngine` can be told (of course from another thread, like your GUI thread) to abort the execution:

[`QScriptEngine::abortEvaluation(const QScriptValue & result = QScriptValue())`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qscriptengine.html#abortEvaluation)

The optional parameter is used as the "pseudo result" which is passed to the caller of [`evaluate()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qscriptengine.html#evaluate).

You should either set a flag somewhere or use a special result value in [`abortEvaluation()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qscriptengine.html#abortEvaluation) to make it possible for the caller routine to detect that the execution was aborted.

Note: Using [`isEvaluating()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qscriptengine.html#isEvaluating) you can see if an evaluation is currently running.